# Dynamic delay configuration to find file size or line count

Tags: spring-integration

I have spring xd aws-s3 source  and  I have configured to change to poller delay depending on my file size.Now in my trigger advice `afterReceive` method How can i get  fileSize or lineCount inside my file from `Message<?> result`?Ideally line count can be good so i can tune delay according to lines or file size

```
 stream create aws-s3|log
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
           xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
           xmlns:int-aws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/aws"
           xmlns:int-file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/aws http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/aws/spring-integration-aws-1.0.xsd">


        <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:dms-security-${region}.properties"   />

        <int:poller fixed-delay="${fixedDelay}" default="true"   trigger="dynamicTrigger" ">
            <int:advice-chain>
                <ref bean="pollAdvise" />
                <ref bean="smartPollAdvise" />
            </int:advice-chain>
        </int:poller>


    <bean id="dynamicTrigger"
            class="org.springframework.integration.util.DynamicPeriodicTrigger">
            <constructor-arg name="period" value="5000" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="pollAdvise" class="org.springframework.integration.scheduling.PollSkipAdvice">
            <constructor-arg ref="healthCheckStrategy"/>

        </bean>

    <bean id="smartPollAdvise" class="com.test.api.dms.main.TriggerAdvise">
             <property name="trigger" ref="dynamicTrigger"/>

        </bean>


        <bean id="healthCheckStrategy" class="com.test.api.dms.main.ServiceHealthCheckPollSkipStrategy">
            <property name="url" value="${url}"/>
            <property name="doHealthCheck" value="${doHealthCheck}"/>
            <property name="restTemplate" ref="restTemplate"/>

        </bean>

        <bean id="restTemplate"
              class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
            <constructor-arg ref="requestFactory"/>

        </bean>


        <bean id="requestFactory"
              class="com.test.api.dms.main.BatchClientHttpRequestFactory">
            <constructor-arg ref="verifier"/>

        </bean>

        <bean id="verifier"
              class="com.test.api.dms.main.NullHostnameVerifier">

        </bean>


        <bean id="encryptedDatum" class="com.test.api.dms.core.security.EncryptedSecuredDatum"/>




        <!-- aws-endpoint="https://s3.amazonaws.com"  proxyHost="proxy.kdc.test.com" proxyPort="8099"-->
        <bean id="clientConfiguration" class="com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration">
            <property name="proxyHost" value="${proxyHost}"/>
            <property name="proxyPort" value="${proxyPort}"/>
            <property name="preemptiveBasicProxyAuth" value="false"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="s3Operations" class="com.test.api.dms.main.CustomC1AmazonS3Operations">

            <constructor-arg index="0" ref="clientConfiguration"/>
            <property name="awsEndpoint" value="s3.amazonaws.com"/>
            <property name="temporaryDirectory" value="${temporaryDirectory}"/>
            <property name="awsSecurityKey"  value="#{encryptedDatum.decryptBase64Encoded('${awsSecurityKey}')}"/>
        </bean>


        <bean id="credentials" class="org.springframework.integration.aws.core.BasicAWSCredentials">

        </bean>

        <!-- aws-endpoint="https://s3.amazonaws.com"  -->
        <int-aws:s3-inbound-channel-adapter aws-endpoint="s3.amazonaws.com"
                                            bucket="${bucket}"
                                            s3-operations="s3Operations"
                                            credentials-ref="credentials"
                                            file-name-wildcard="${fileNameWildcard}"
                                            remote-directory="${prefix}"
                                            channel="splitChannel"
                                            local-directory="${localDirectory}"
                                            accept-sub-folders="false"
                                            delete-source-files="true"
                                            archive-bucket="${archiveBucket}"
                                            archive-directory="${archiveDirectory}">
        </int-aws:s3-inbound-channel-adapter>

        <int-file:splitter input-channel="splitChannel" output-channel="output" markers="false" charset="UTF-8">

            <int-file:request-handler-advice-chain>
                <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
                    <property name="onSuccessExpression" value="payload.delete()"/>
                </bean>
            </int-file:request-handler-advice-chain>

        </int-file:splitter>

        <int:channel-interceptor pattern="*" order="3">
            <bean class="org.springframework.integration.channel.interceptor.WireTap">
                <constructor-arg ref="loggingChannel" />
            </bean>
        </int:channel-interceptor>
        <int:logging-channel-adapter id="loggingChannel" log-full-message="true" level="INFO"/>

        <int:channel id="output"/>

    </beans>



public class TriggerAdvice extends AbstractMessageSourceAdvice {

    private final DynamicPeriodicTrigger trigger;


    private volatile long nextPollPeriod;


    public TriggerAdvice(DynamicPeriodicTrigger trigger) {
        this.trigger = trigger;
        this.nextPollPeriod = trigger.getPeriod();
    }


    public long getNextPollPeriod() {
        return nextPollPeriod;
    }


    public void setNextPollPeriod(long nextPollPeriod) {
        this.nextPollPeriod = nextPollPeriod;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean beforeReceive(MessageSource<?> source) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Message<?> afterReceive(Message<?> result, MessageSource<?> source) {
        if (result == null) {
            this.trigger.setPeriod(this.nextPollPeriod);
        }
        return null;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `aws-s3 source` returns the `Message<File>`, so your `afterReceive` can just cast the `getPayload()` and use standard Java mechanism to count lines from the file:

```
LineNumberReader  lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader((File) result.getPayload());
lnr.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
System.out.println(lnr.getLineNumber() + 1); //Add 1 because line index starts at 0
// Finally, the LineNumberReader object should be closed to prevent resource leak
lnr.close();
```